# Moka pot induction heater

Tags: espresso-machine, equipment, moka, induction

I was wondering whether there was such a thing as a small induction heater/hob for moka pots? I have a small moka pot which I loath using on my electric hob. I think it is a waste of energy given that the smallest hot plate is significantly larger than my little moka pot. It would be great if I can get a small induction hob that I can just keep in the dining room to use when I fancy a post-dinner tipple. Another benefit for an induction hob is that it shouldn't get significantly hot, making it ideal for the dining room.

Regards.

Comment: Look out for [this effect](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1926/262) if your induction hob cycles on and off!

Comment: Also, check your moka pot will actually work on an induction hob. It needs to be magnetic (just test it yourself with a magnet), and have a large enough base. Some smaller pots may not 'register' on the hob. You'll probably want to try out a hob with your pot before you buy it.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually get all-in-one moka pots that plug directly into the mains, e.g.:

[http://www.amazon.com/Delonghi-EMK6-Alicia-Electric-Espresso/dp/B00009W5F0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009W5F0)

[image]

I've used one similar to this before, the results aren't bad!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search, I found [this product](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Judge-JEA11-Portable-Induction-Hob/dp/B001TIPRN2) and it seems pretty nice.

That shows me that *small induction hobs* does exists, so you'll find one easily.

Comment: Cool - thanks. Though I was hoping for something that was small enough for a moka pot, rather than being pan sized. Still worth a consideration.

Comment: @pete As far as I'm aware, the 'size' of induction hobs doesn't affect their efficiency. No heat can be wasted outside of the footprint of the pan since the pan itself is directly heated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I purchased my first moka pot set from tabao (the Chinese equivalent of Amazon), and it came with a small induction plate thing. Its radius is just right for the base of my 6-cup moka pot. Works very well for me and my subsequent moka pots. Perhaps you can find something similar in your country?

[image: Moka pot induction]

https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.122.311b103608Vh7B&id=559978486817&ns=1&abbucket=3#detail

Answer (score -1):

Though it will get hot, a small stand-alone laboratory or kitchen [hot plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_plate) is still a good alternative to induction. They can be small and inexpensive; here's [one example from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007QCRNU) that has about a 15cm/6in element.

Comment: Where do you get them?

Comment: These may work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_gauze Chemical lab equipment stores or online.

Comment: A nice thought, but OP said he was not interested in hot plates. I took the liberty of editing as an example of an augmented answer with links.